# orterun command not found while using the hostfile to use mpi on multiple nodes

Tags: mpi, hpc, pbs

I want to run the mpi on multiple computing nodes, in the first node I need to use 48 cpu and 4 gpu, and 6 ranks, in the second node I should use 48 cpu and 4 gpu but 5 ranks.

I tried to create the hostfile to tell all this information to the nodes, but I am getting

```
line 37: orterun: command not found
```

the run script (which included the pbs script) is :

```
#!/bin/bash
#PBS -l walltime=00:05:00
#PBS -l ncpus=48
#PBS -l ngpus=4
#PBS -l mem=384GB
#PBS -l jobfs=100GB
#PBS -q gpuvolta
#PBS -P kv03
#PBS -l wd


if [ -f debug.h5 ]; then
  rm debug.h5
fi

# hostfilename
hostfile=hostfile_$PBS_JOBID

#for gadi MBE runs
NODE_LIST=$(cat $PBS_NODEFILE | sort | uniq)
i=0
for word in $NODE_LIST
do
    if [ $i == 0 ] 
    then
        echo "$word slots=6 max_slots=6" >> $hostfile
    else
        echo "$word slots=5 max_slots=5" >> $hostfile
    fi  
    i=$((i+1))
done
echo "$hostfile created"
#(cat $hostfile)

# linux using openmpi
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=1
orterun --mca btl vader,self,tcp -np 6 --bind-to core --hostfile $hostfile ./exe1 w6-new.json
```

If I was working with one node my oreturn command was

```
orterun --mca btl vader,self,tcp -np 6 --bind-to core --map-by ppr:6:node ./exe1 w6-new.json
```

which was correct.

for running on multiple nodes, shall I put the number of whole ranks (in both nodes) in oreturn command? and also the pbs script should be for whole two nodes (96 cpu and 8 gpu) or just per each node (like the one that I wrote in the script)

Comment: try using the absolute path to `orterun`

Comment: Thanks @GillesGouaillardet I did this /Home/test/$hostfile but It didn't fix the problem

Comment: it should be the absolute path to `orterun`, for example `/opt/openmpi/bin/orterun`